# Trying to Replicate Code but Map Won't Populate in Background

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet, mapbox

I'm trying to recreate the Leaflet map from the following link.

http://bl.ocks.org/adg29/6f5f9750afaae0ce68a8

However, like in the url, I can't get a map to populate in the background - which it does here (the link below) and to my recollection the code is the same. Can someone assist me with this?

Where map works:

http://zevross.com/blog/2014/09/30/use-the-amazing-d3-library-to-animate-a-path-on-a-leaflet-map/

Here is my code (w/ public access token):

```
 L.mapbox.accessToken = '<access token>';

var mapboxTiles = 
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/examples.map- 
zr0njcqy/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '<a href="http://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/" 
target="_blank">Terms &amp; Feedback</a>'
});
var map = L.map('map', {accessToken: '<access token>'})
    .addLayer(mapboxTiles) 
    .setView([40.72332345541449, -73.99], 14);
```

Comment: Mapbox is a commercial tiles provider. You need to provide an API key.

Comment: @kboul thank you for responding. I added a public access token however I still can't get the map to populate. I added a few lines of code above with what I did - is it possible for you to take a look to see what I did wrong? thank you so much

Comment: Do you mind if I provide an example with opensource tiles? openstreet map for instance